# Facebook API send automated private messages to yourself

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, api

I'm using Facebook Connect on my website. I need to enable users to send themselves automated private messages from my site to their Facebook account. Does the Facebook API allow this?

Edit: I found a solution https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/ however I need to send messages without the user interacting with the write message pop up. Messages should be sent directly if possible because they are automated, set up by the user once.

Comment: Not sure if it is quite what you're after but I'd look at using xmpp https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/, there are loads of examples about how to do this in php also.

Comment: read here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken

Comment: @Louis, thanks that a good alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can send to their facebook email. Facebook email is consisting profile nickname+'@facebook.com'. The email will goes to their facebook inbox message. Note that facebook email does not accept spoofing email. You will need whitelabel domain or use SendGrid.