# Facebook - How to send automated private messages to friends now (Oct. 2015)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was researching this topic and I found that [there was an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/send-private-messages-to-friends) in StackOverflow in 2013. It uses ["send dialog" api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) of Facebook.

However it couldn't send automated/pre-filled message on behalf of the user. Is it still true now as of Oct. 2015?

[Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560161/facebook-api-send-automated-private-messages-to-yourself) was asked here in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, prefilling is not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). That being said, the Chat API is gone and there is no alternative. You can't send messages with any API anymore, you can only use the Send or Message Dialogs. See official docs for more information about those.

Automated messages to friends would ALWAYS be spam, so there is a good reason why it is not possible and not allowed.